# How to detect when an action is complete before moving onto another action?

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

I am trying to click a button that would fun a function to move an object from point to another point. Once that action is complete then move to the second point.

```
    @IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {

    spawnToIntersection1()
    intersectionToIntersection2()
}



func spawnToIntersection1() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 6, animations: {
        self.playerTester.center = CGPoint(x: self.intersection1.center.x , y: self.intersection1.center.y)
    }, completion: nil)
}

func intersectionToIntersection2() {


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 6, animations: {
        self.playerTester.center = CGPoint(x: self.intersection2.center.x , y: self.intersection2.center.y)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your `intersectionToIntersection2()` in `completion` block of first animation

```
func spawnToIntersection1() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 6, animations: {
        self.playerTester.center = CGPoint(x: self.intersection1.center.x , y: self.intersection1.center.y)
    }, completion: _ in { 
        intersectionToIntersection2()
       })
}
```

And then just call

```
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
    spawnToIntersection1()
}
```